# Postgres.app Could not start on port 5432

Tags: macos, postgresql

I'm using http://postgresapp.com. In the menubar it gives the error " Could not start on port 5432." Similarly if I try to start the server from the terminal, I get:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I also ran `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start`
and got the output `server starting` but still get the same errors when connecting to psql.

Comment: My first guess is that port 5432 is taken by something else on your mac.  By default psql will not use the port, but instead use the socket file (`/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432`) as you mentioned.  You can force it to use the port with `psql -h localhost`.  Try checking a couple of things: 1 is anything else using port 5432.  2: check that your postgres (OS) user has access to create files in /tmp/.

Comment: I see something in /tmp/ that is .s.PSQL.5433 How can I change that to 5432?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I think it's related to an update of pro applications from Apple, because that's the only change I made, then I started getting this error. I've tried uninstalling and re-installing postgresql; uninstalling and re-installing the pg gem; and a few other configuration tweaks, but no results. Still working on it, but hope to see a solution soon. I will let you know if I make any progress.

Comment: In my case, I had dBeaver running connected to my postgresql instance.  I made a config change and clicked "Stop" and "Start" and was perplexed to get the "port in use" error.  But the "lsof -i :5432" suggested below showed dBeaver had the port tied up. Killed dBeaver and postgresql started up just fine.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You my have another instance of postgres running, that is the only application interested in this port. You should use netstat and ps to determine this. Then stop the instance and uninstall it, you mayhave installed enterpiseDb for example, that is what I did.

Comment: In my case this just happens randomly after some days of installing PostGreSQL on MacOSX. I then reinstall and everything works and then again after few days, it shows the same error. I want to make clear that i never change my root password for PostGreSQL. Please help

Answer (score 92):

If you are running your server on a macOS machine and installed Postgres through Homebrew, you can stop the current instance like this:

> brew services stop postgresql

Then click the Elephant in the native menu-bar at the top of the screen and it should successfully startup.

Comment: where is the menu bar ? :')

Comment: Good catch!  I've clarified which menu bar I meant.  Thanks!

Comment: @MaxvonHippel Thank you so much my friend, you really made my day :)

Answer (score 77):

You can stop the process by finding the PID with

```
lsof -i :5432
```

and then killing it with

```
kill -9 <PID>
```

Comment: this is the most general method that works for any port. Should be the best answer

Comment: When I kill it, again it is running at different PID. please help

Comment: @Tula https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158194/kill-a-process-that-keeps-restarting

Comment: I tried this but it would just start running with another PID. What worked for me is `brew services stop postgresql`

Comment: you need sudo for this to work

Answer (score 34):

If you've installed Postgres via another method (for example, from www.postgresql.org) and it's starting automatically at startup, you can prevent that Postgres from starting via the following:

```
sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.edb.launchd.postgresql-X.X.plist  
sudo rm -f /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.edb.launchd.postgresql-X.X.plist
```

**TIP: use tab to autocomplete after the `com.edb.launchd` part to figure out what version is loading.**

Restart Postgres.app and you should be good to go.

(from http://forums.enterprisedb.com/posts/list/1831.page;jsessionid=70621DC48C99EDE663A6A594B05F1A02#6782)

Comment: thanks a lot. This has worked for me. The issue was that whenever i killed the process listening on 5432, it launched again -_-. Thanks again

Comment: Life saver (need more words to comment this) :D

Answer (score 24):

I was just having this exact issue.  When I ran `which psql` it was pointing at the Postgres client tools installed with Lion:

`/usr/bin/psql`

Using a hint from [Frank Wiles](http://www.revsys.com/writings/postgresql/errors.html#cannot-connect-local) I ran `ps auxw | grep post` to confirm that postgres was running and that it was running on the right port, that also showed me the postgres.app path:

`/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/postgres`.

So I edited by .bash_profile to export that directory.  On first effort I added it to the end of the path.  When I ran `echo $PATH` I could see that usr/bin was the first thing in the path, and `which psql` still gave the `/usr/bin` path.  At that point a friend guided me in the right direction:

`export PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:${PATH}"`

Start a new terminal window, then run `which psql` -- it should point to the postgres.app location and psql should fire up the postgres shell.  Works fine now.

Comment: for 9.3 my path was export PATH="/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:${PATH}"

Answer (score 23):

This command is a one-liner that instantly kills all PostgresSQL processes.

```
sudo kill -kill $(sudo lsof -t -i :5432)
```

This fixed all my problems on Mac OSX Mojave 10.14.1.

Comment: I regret running this command, I killed my entire postgress and now it cannot start.

Comment: This is dangerous. You don't want to kill the base system postgres.

Answer (score 18):

I have tried just about every solution to this problem that is out there. For me it always happens when my MacBook's battery dies, even if the computer is already sleeping. I was poking around in `~/Library/Application\ Support/Postgres/var-9.4` and I discovered another `postmaster.pid` file that I had not seen before. I deleted it, and now everything is back up and running! I am running the Postgres.app version, not the brew version.

Steps I took:

1. Make sure `postgres.app` is not running.
2. Run `rm ~/Library/Application\ Support/Postgres/var-9.$X/postmaster.pid`
3. If you don't have a `var-9.$X` directory, just run `rm ~/Library/Application\ Support/Postgres/postmaster.pid`
4. Restart `postgres.app`
5. Get back to developing cool stuff.

Comment: I had the same issue. This answer provided solution on my end. The key part is to make sure the system wouldn't be able to read that `postmaster.pid` file. Removing it via `rm` or just renaming it via `mv` would do. I prefer renaming it to `postmaster.pid.problem-cause` though. People have different installation setups so the best way to find that nasty file is to check the PosgtreSQL logs.

Answer (score 11):

I generally face this issue on my mac, and this fixes it for me always

```
rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid
brew services restart postgresql
```

Hope this is helpful

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem where I could not connect to the Postgres.app even though the app itself said that it is running on port 5432.

I am not sure why, but even when I quit the app and checked that no postgres processes was running with ps -a. these files existed:

```
/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

and

```
/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock
```

My solution was to delete these files and then start the postgres.app again.

Comment: This solved the problem for me.  Not sure why this answer was downvoted by others unless it's for some reason dangerous to delete `/tmp` files.

Comment: I got excited at first, when seeing those files via `su` (superuser) and deleting them, but no joy

Comment: I tried "brew services stop postgresql" then deleted the /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock

Answer (score 9):

This is what worked for me:
$ sudo pkill -u postgres

Props to this resource:
https://github.com/PostgresApp/PostgresApp/issues/197#issuecomment-474534056

Answer (score 5):

It can also happen that the PID is taken.
This ocurred to me when the Computer suffered an unexpected reboot.

If so, you must go to:

```
˜/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var-9.4
```

You can check that path in Postgres.app Preferences dialog.

And then, just remove the pid file

```
sudo rm postmaster.pid
```

And the server starts up right away.

Comment: No such file in that folder. I am using PostGres 9.6 and couldnt find any file ending in that extension.

Comment: Then your pid is not taken and something else is going on.

Answer (score 4):

When trying to open the Postgres app was getting that same error regarding post 5432 (on Mac OSX 10.10.5)

I did:

```
$ lsof -i | grep LISTEN
```

Saw which PID was running postgres at that port, did:
`$ killall {pid}` and then `$ brew uninstall postgres`

After that, restarted my Mac, and ran:

`$ lsof -i | grep LISTEN` again just to make sure. Saw no postgres running anywhere and was able to open the Postgres app without getting that warning.

Then I reinstalled postgres with `$ brew install postgres`

**ANOTHER OPTION**:

*(I also tried this one time when the above approach didn't work and I could not kill any of the PID)*

```
$ ps auxw | grep post
```

Saw a slew postgres processes, which I then `sudo kill <PID>`

Everything working fine now.

Comment: Why do you want an postgres installed by homebrew and from the Postgres.app?

Answer (score 3):

For those using mac, this code worked for me like charm.

```
sudo pkill -u postgres
```

Answer (score 2):

At a guess, something else had taken port 5432 so the app chose to run on 5433 instead.

Why not just connect to Pg on port 5433, if that's where it's running? You have a `/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432` socket file, so you can connect with `psql -p 5433` for UNIX domain socket connections. It'll also be listening on the same port with TCP/IP, so you can use `psql -h localhost -p 5433` for TCP/IP and have your apps connect to port 5433 instead of 5432.

Change your `.psqlrc` to set the new port as default and you can forget it isn't on the default port.

Comment: Every option is worth exploring at this point, but this did not work for me. I am planning on re-installing the operating system at this point because I have not been able to remedy.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem when trying to use postgresql with rails. Updating my Gemfile to use new version of gem pg solve this problem for me. (gem pg version 0.16.0 works). In the Gemfile use:

```
gem 'pg', '0.16.0'
```

then run the following to update the gem

```
bundle install --without production
bundle update
bundle install
```

Answer (score 1):

Mine failed to start up suddenly, and when I checked Console.app I saw:

```
com.heroku.postgres-service: 
FATAL:  could not create shared memory segment: Cannot allocate memory
DETAIL:  Failed system call was shmget(key=5432001, size=3874816, 03600).
HINT:  This error usually means that PostgreSQL's request for a shared memory segment exceeded available memory or swap space, or exceeded your kernel's SHMALL parameter.  You can either reduce the request size or reconfigure the kernel with larger SHMALL.  To reduce the request size (currently 3874816 bytes), reduce PostgreSQL's shared memory usage, perhaps by reducing shared_buffers or max_connections.
The PostgreSQL documentation contains more information about shared memory configuration.
```

It turns out Postgres wouldn't start up because I had Wireshark (and X11) running. It worked fine after I quit Wireshark.

Good luck!

Comment: I also had postgres.app fail to start up properly while X11 was running, killing X11 and restarting the app again fixed it. Mysterious problem.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this problem by

1. Identifying what was running on port 5432 by using "netstat" in the CL, which was postgreSQL not Postgres
2. I located the directory that contained postgreSQL, which was root/Library/PostgreSQL
3. I ensured an instants of the application wasn't running via Activity Monitor
4. Then I deleted the folder and rebooted! Everything was fine!

Answer (score 1):

Somehow I totally forgot that this socket file will be hidden because of the dot. Make sure you use `ls -A /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432` if you are checking to see if the socket is actually there.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely has a PostgreSQL installed, deleted it and installed it again. PostgreSQL typically used port 5432 but if not available, increases to the next available one, in this case 5433. So, you probably chose this port on your second install.

I think you should check file:

**/etc/services**

and adjust rows below for your expected port number:

**postgresql      5432/udp    # PostgreSQL Database**

**postgresql      5432/tcp    # PostgreSQL Database**

After this you should restart your computer (simplest way).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

In my case it was a corrupt host file on my mac. I was missing:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

A quick easy way to check is to open terminal and type:

```
ping localhost
```

or:

```
scutil -r localhost
```

More info [here](https://github.com/PostgresApp/PostgresApp/issues/200#)
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Netstat, ps aux, etc ... none showed 5432 in use.  Checked /Library.  Found PG9.6 old install still there.  Did rm -rf and bang.  Version 11 works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I was losing my mind over this problem! i kept running

> lsof -i | grep 5432

and nothing was showing up!
finally i ran it using sudo and a potgres client showed up.
so if anyone else has tried the lsof and went nowhere, try it with sudo.

> sudo lsof -i | grep 5432

and then

> sudo kill <the_pid_from_postgresql_found_from_lsof>

Answer (score 0):

The same problem just happened to me. I had Postgres.app 9.2.4.1 running since a while. When I updated Mac OS X to 10.8.5, after the mandatory reboot it was not working anymore. I tried several things, including updating to 9.2.4.3 and neither after another reboot it was working.

I had to open the file `/Users/$USER/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var/postgresql.conf` and to:

1. uncomment line `unix_socket_permissions = 0777`
2. uncomment and adapt line `unix_socket_directory = '/tmp'`

After a restart, Postgres.app was running like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

A file named "postmaster.pid" (in my $PGDATA directory) were preventing postgresql to start. It was a zombie file, placed there 10 days ago and when I brutally shut down the computer (pulling the plug, literally), no clean up process had the opportunity to remove that file.

Answer (score 0):

beside all the helpful answers, you might also want to take a look at official page instructions :
[postgressapp.com/documentation/remove.html](https://postgresapp.com/documentation/remove.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and mine was caused by some configuration issues I was having. Clearing the user configurations and reinstalling postgres in brew worked for me!

```js
brew uninstall postgresql
rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres
```

Comment: This was the issue in my case, Postgres was silently running from terminal and the installer app is unable to connect to the port 5432

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following:

`psql --version` then `brew services stop postgresql@<VERSION>`

finally, start your `Postgres` app on your Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem,

TO solve, goto /tmp

The files you are looking for might be hidden so CMD+SHIFT+. will make them visible then delete

these files:
/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhez3.png)
/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock

you might need to restart your computer to get it working

Answer (score -1):

1. Change the port: Port 5432 is the default port for PostgreSQL but like any other server you spin up in your machine, it could also run on any port. Change it to another port, in the screen below, I changed mine to Port 5433.

[image]

2. Update your project port.

```
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://db_user:db_password@localhost:5433/your_db?schema=public"

JWT_SECRET="YOUR_SECRET"

PORT="YOUR_PORT"
```

[See the post I made about it for more details](https://medium.com/@brytebee/how-to-fix-port-5432-is-already-in-use-in-macos-88b63768a2ed)

Comment: brytebee, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Useful edits could be to explain how to check the port and how to update it

Comment: @mozway thanks for the heads-up, I'll update it immediately.

Comment: Thanks, note that the second image should rather be in text format since it's just code.