# Cannot start Postgres on port 5432

Tags: postgresql, macos, postgres.app

I just installed [postgres.app](https://postgresapp.com/), but when I try to start the server I get the following error:

[image]

After checking some answers in a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028037/postgres-app-could-not-start-on-port-5432) I verified that my `PATH` is defined correctly and that no other process is running on port 5432:

[image]

So what's going on with port 5432?

Comment: Your question is duplicate on https://stackoverflow.com/a/12945959/11871997

Comment: Read through my post, that link was already mentioned. I have read through that post and it is not a duplicate. While the errors are very similar, I do not have postgres installed or running elsewhere.

Comment: `lsof -i` only shows ports listened to by processes owned by the current user (unless you are root) or something like that, so the fact that something doesn't show doesn't mean it isn't there.

Comment: See solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78073275/11737951). I posted it on another thread.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution. Uninstalled and reinstalled and now everything works on port 5432. Very strange error, I am curious if anyone has any ideas about how this happened.